# Properly fit the views inside GridLayout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I have four views inside `GridLayout` called `com.app.views.deals.DealsTabletButton`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.app.views.InfoHeading
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/info_header_height"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_gray_solid_white" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
                    <!-- ViewPager Implemenatation -->
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
                        android:id="@+id/deals_container"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
                        app:columnCount="2">


                        <com.app.views.deals.DealsTabletButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:d_icon="@drawable/deals_icon_red"
                            app:d_lower_text="@string/all_deals_right_active_now"
                            app:d_text="@string/deals"
                            app:d_upper_text="@string/view" />

                        <com.app.views.deals.DealsTabletButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            app:d_icon="@drawable/categories_icon_red"
                            app:d_lower_text="@string/over_500_top_categories"
                            app:d_text="@string/category"
                            app:d_upper_text="@string/shop_by" />


                        <com.app.views.deals.DealsTabletButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            app:d_icon="@drawable/brands_icon_red"
                            app:d_lower_text="@string/over_2500_popular_brands"
                            app:d_text="@string/brand"
                            app:d_upper_text="@string/shop_by" />

                        <com.app.views.deals.DealsTabletButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            app:d_is_empty="true" />

                    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/home_screen_sector_spacing"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:text="@string/best_seller"
                            android:textColor="@color/heading_gray"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/all_best_sellers"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:textColor="@color/hyper_link"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <!-- Others views -->

    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

There is `DealsTabletButton` layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:background="@drawable/border_gray_solid_white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.app.opticsplanet.views.SvgImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            app:b_icon="@drawable/deals_icon_red" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="View"
                android:id="@+id/upperText"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DEALS"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lowerText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="All Deals Active Right Now!"
                android:textColor="@color/heading_gray"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the `DealsTableButton` implementation:

```
public class DealsTabletButton extends FrameLayout {

    private final String upperText;
    private final String lowerText;
    private final String text;
    @InjectView(R.id.icon)
    SvgImageView mIcon;
    @InjectView(R.id.upperText)
    TextView mUpperText;
    @InjectView(R.id.text)
    TextView mText;
    @InjectView(R.id.lowerText)
    TextView mLowerText;
    @InjectView(R.id.container)
    LinearLayout mContainer;
    private Drawable icon;
    boolean isEmpty = false;

    public DealsTabletButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.deals_button, 0, 0);

        try {
            int iconId = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.deals_button_d_icon, -1);
            upperText = ta.getString(R.styleable.deals_button_d_upper_text);
            lowerText = ta.getString(R.styleable.deals_button_d_lower_text);
            text = ta.getString(R.styleable.deals_button_d_text);
            isEmpty = ta.getBoolean(R.styleable.deals_button_d_is_empty, false);
            if (iconId != -1) {
                icon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(this.getContext(), iconId);

            }

        } finally {
            ta.recycle();
        }

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.deals_tablet_button, this, true);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);

        if (isEmpty) setEmptyView();
        else setViews();

    }

    private void setEmptyView() {
        mIcon.setImage(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.add_icon));
        mUpperText.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.add_your));
        mText.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.shortcut));
        mLowerText.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.to_specific_Department_Category_or_Brand));
        mContainer.setBackground(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_gray_solid_background_nop));
    }

    private void setViews() {
        if (icon != null) {
            mIcon.setImage(icon);
        }
        mText.setText(text);
        mLowerText.setText(lowerText + "\n");
        mUpperText.setText(upperText);
    }

}
```

The actual result in portrait mode is:

[image]

The red ones arrows represents expected result. How can I to arrange properly these `DealsTabletButton`'s inside `GridLayout` ?

After screen rotation to landscape mode I would like to have all views in one row and there is my implemenation:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        changeColumnCount(4);
        mDealsContainer.setRowCount(1);
    } else {
        changeColumnCount(2);
        mDealsContainer.setRowCount(2);
    }
}

private void changeColumnCount(int columnCount) {
    if (mDealsContainer.getColumnCount() != columnCount) {
        final int viewsCount = mDealsContainer.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < viewsCount; i++) {
            View view = mDealsContainer.getChildAt(i);
            //new GridLayout.LayoutParams created with Spec.UNSPECIFIED
            //which are package visible
            view.setLayoutParams(new GridLayout.LayoutParams());
        }
        mDealsContainer.setColumnCount(columnCount);
    }
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

**Problem**

In portrait mode I would like to *stretch* views to the red line.

In landscape mode I would like to *narrow* views to the red line.

Hope my question is clear, anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To stretch the views, add `android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"` to the cells.

For narrowing the views, your best bet is reducing the width of the content in your cell view.  You can also try using weighted views.  Weights are only supported since API 21, but you can use the `GridLayout` from the support library:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            .
            .
            .

            <com.app.views.deals.DealsTabletButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                .
                .
                .
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has changed

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not familiar with ButterKnife.  It may be possible that the call to `super(context, attrs)` is setting the gravity correctly, then the injection of the view (which doesn't have the gravity set) by ButterKnife may be wiping it out.  I would try adding the inflated view as a child to your component without using ButterKnife just to see what happens.  In other words, just call `addView(view)`.  The gravity/weight in the layout params is the key to getting the cell view to stretch.